# UTC to locatime with daylight saving

Tags: c#, utc, datetimeoffset, gmt

We are saving all dates in UTC in our database and also saving offset for each user.

We are converting to localtime by following function:

```
 Private Function ConvertToLocalDateTime(ByVal utcOffset As Integer?, ByVal DateToConvert As DateTime?) As DateTime?

        getdatetime = DateToConvert.Value.AddHours(utcOffset)

        If getdatetime.IsDaylightSavingTime Then
            getdatetime.AddHours(-1)
        End If

        Return getdatetime
    End Function
```

But still dates are 1 or 2 hours off.

How can we convert correctly to localtime from utcoffset also taking care of daylight saving?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tolocaltime?view=netframework-4.8 . *The conversion also takes into account the daylight saving time rule that applies to the time represented by the current DateTime object. *

Comment: It's not clear to me why you take a UTC offset as a parameter. Instead, you should take a TimeZoneInfo, as that knows the time zone rules to apply in any situation. If you've only recorded the UTC offset for your users at a particular point in time, you don't have enough information.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the [`Kind`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.kind) property on `DateToConvert` is set properly to `Utc`, then you can just call [`DateToConvert.ToLocalTime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tolocaltime).